# Django how to check if username already exists and return gracefully

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

Django checks if the entered user name already exists and if it exists it falls with an error.

I want it to check if username exists the same as he checks if email is valid or that the passwords are matched, i.e. return the appropriate HTML message to the user.

this is my attempt to do it from view.py

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Unpack form values
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

        # Create the User record    
        user = User(username=username, email=email,
                    first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            context= {'form': form, 'error':'The username you entered has already been taken. Please try another username.'}
            return render(request, template, context)
```

this is my html form (the relevant part):

```
                <h5 class="sn-sh">CREATE A USERNAME AND PASSWORD</h5>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ form.username.label }}</th>
                        <th>{{ form.email.label }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form.email }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form.username.errors }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form.email.errors }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Confirm Password</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form.password1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form.password2 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form.password1.errors }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form.password2.errors }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Currently it is not crush but does not return any message to the user ... (nothing really happens)

What am I doing wrong? How can I get him to send a nice message to the user?

I tried using ValidationError - but it also just crashed and sent an ugly message to the user

-----  edit ----
I added an ugly solution that work

I added to forms.py this lines:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
.
.
.
class SubscriberForm(AddressMixin, UserCreationForm):
.
.
.
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']

    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():     
        raise forms.ValidationError("User name already exist, please choose new one")
    return username
```

This solution as far as I tested work - but it's ugly and feels rung (I now have  views.py functionality inside of forms.py - hope that you guise have a better solution that keep the django model clean